# ¿Cómo poner en una lista las sentencias condicionales en Python?

Tags: python, condiciones

Código Python, 3.6:

```
#base de datos contienes filas (relaciones) de la forma:
#(id autoincremented, booleanos, columna3, columna4)
# ejm: ( 1,       "A||B||C",   "datos1", "datos2")


def funcion(booleanos):
    global lista1
    global lista2
    
    '''toma a `booleanos` y lo consulta a la base de datos para recuperar 
       columna3, y columna4'''

    lista1=columna3
    lista2=columna4

    return lista1,lista2
    
    
if A:
    if B:
        if C:
            funcion('A||B||C')
        elif D:
            funcion('A||B||D')
    elif E:
        if C:
            funcion('A||E||C')
        elif D:
            funcion('A||E||D')

# el programa solo tomara un camino en las condicionales de acuerdo a la 
#situacion e imprimira las listas asignadas por los booleanos

print(lista1)
print(lista2)
```

Entonces la pregunta sería, **¿como darle el argumento automáticamente a funcion(bool) sin hacerlo manualmente en las condicionales**, ya que como dije en comentarios son muchos.
Ademas el formato de `booleanos` puede ser diferente si es que se requiere, es decir puede ser: `'if A||if B||if C'`, etc.

Comment: Hola Norvin, ¿qué debería hacer la función en base a lo recibido exactamente? Poder pasarlas puedes, también pasar el resultado de evaluar las expresiones (lista de boleanos)  `funcion([a ==6, b==7, c==8]`, la cuestión, más en si se puede pasar o no  es cómo la función debe procesar eso.

Comment: Hola @ FJSevilla , es que esas expresiones las use como iid de los items de un treeview , por lo tanto la funcion deberia tomar estas expresiones de las condicionales y consultarlo a la base de datos de iids del treeview y tomar datos relacionados con el iid , no se si me explique bien.lo estoy haciendo manualmente , pero son hasta miles , por lo que i existiera la manera de ponerlos en lista , me ahorraria mucho..sds.

Comment: Pero me temo que no hay manera de hacerlo ,verdad?

Comment: Mas facil de entender . es como si la funcion tomara esta lista y la consulta en un diccionario y luego imprime su resultado.

Comment: Sería bueno que explicaras cuál es tu problema de fondo, qué intentas resolver. De este modo podremos ayudarte a encontrar una solución práctica

Comment: Norvin si por algo se caracteriza Python es porque hay muy pocas cosas que nos nos deje hacer, para bien o para mal... El problema es que consigamos comprender la situación, a veces es más complicado explicarla que la solución... Según entiendo as usado cadenas de la forma  "a==6" como identificadores en el Tree. Tu problema sería  generar las cadenas por tanto. No se si sigo perdido, pero podrías usar formateo de cadenas : `funcion([f'a=={a}', f'b=={b}', f'c=={c}'])`

Comment: Voy a reeditar la pregunta con el problema de fondo.

Comment: Cuantas letras necesitas solo A,B,C,D,E? si B es `False`, debe ir a validar E? por que no C?

Comment: Pues si B es `False`, E tendria que ser `True`,osea si o si uno tendría que ser  `True`.   Es solo un ejemplo para exxplicar la situacion.

Answer (score 0):

Por planteamiento tenemos variables A, B, C, ... que contiene el resultado de alguna expresión lógica cualquiera.

Aplicando la nueva instrucción `match` (similar al CASE en otros lenguanes):

```
match a, b, c, d, e:
    case True, True, False, True, _:
        print("A||B||D")
    case True, True, True, _, _:
        print("A||B||C")
    case True, False, True, _, True:
        print('A||E||C')
    case True, False, False, True, True:
        print('A||E||D')
    case _ : print()
```

Toma la lista de expresiones dadas, las calculas y luego recorre cada caso (`case`) viendo si lo calculado coincide con lo expresado en el `case`.

La sintaxis de `case` es que colocas el valor que debe coincidir, como en

```
    case True, True, False, False, _:
```

que significa que este `case` se ejecutara cuando A==True, B==True, C==False y D==False. Como el valor de E no importa, usamos "_" para indicar que hay que ignorarlo.

Los casos se examinan en orden hasta encontrar el primero que cumple la condición.

Lo anterior se puede aplicar también cuando las condiciones vienen en una lista:

```
condiciones = [a, b, c, d, e]
```

En este caso hay que poner los `case` con listas también, para comparar listas con listas.

```
match condiciones:
    case [True, True, False, True, _]:
         print("A||B||D")
```

**Demo**

```
for a in [True, False]:
    for b in [True, False]:
        for c in [True, False]:
            for d in [True, False]:
                for e in [True, False]:

                    print(a, b, c, d, e, end = " ")
                    match a, b, c, d, e:
                        case True, True, False, True, _:
                            print("A||B||D")
                        case True, True, True, _, _:
                            print("A||B||C")
                        case True, False, True, _, True:
                            print('A||E||C')
                        case True, False, False, True, True:
                            print('A||E||D')
                        case _ : print()
```

produce:

```
True True True True True A||B||C
True True True True False A||B||C
True True True False True A||B||C
True True True False False A||B||C
True True False True True A||B||D
True True False True False A||B||D
True True False False True 
True True False False False 
True False True True True A||E||C
True False True True False 
True False True False True A||E||C
True False True False False 
True False False True True A||E||D
True False False True False 
True False False False True 
True False False False False 
False True True True True 
False True True True False 
False True True False True 
False True True False False 
False True False True True 
False True False True False 
False True False False True 
False True False False False 
False False True True True 
False False True True False 
False False True False True 
False False True False False 
False False False True True 
False False False True False 
False False False False True 
False False False False False 

Process finished with exit code 0
```